# I want the search engine to crawl my page instead of dt_benefits

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm running a WordPress site. When I search a specific page in search engine, it gives me other things besides that page which I don't want. Could someone tell how to avoid such things (`dt_benefits`) from being crawled?

Answer (score 1):

To have crawlers ignore your page, you need to add a meta tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` to each page you'd like not indexed. Alternatively, since you're using Wordpress, I'd recommend installing [Yoast SEO Plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) and noindex your pages through there.

Comment: I have added benefits*feature in visual composer) to my pages .While searching for a specific page it crawls the benefits along with the page(the benefit  have the same name as that of page),i dont want my benefits to be crawled or indexed.What  i need to do for the same(Hope you understand what i said)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Visual Composer, so I'm not sure what the "benefits feature" is, but if it's a post type, you can "noindex" it with Yoast SEO. I would recommend you spend a few minutes reading the documentation for Yoast SEO, maybe start [here](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-do-i-noindex-urls/).